# Upsert Name in ChangeResourceRecordSets

Tags: go, amazon-route53

Forgive me, but I was not able to find this question addressed in 20 mins of googling so I thought I'd ask.  I have bunch of route53 cname and A records that need the name changed on them:

```
cname record:
aaa.xxx.xxx.xxx.com becomes bbb.xxx.xxx.xxx.com
A record:
internal-alb-aaa.xxx.xxx.xxx.com becomes internal-alb-bbb.xxx.xxx.xxx.com
```

I believe this needs to be done with the following api call, but it appears to me the Name: field acts as a sort of primary key so it wouldn't be possible to rename it.

Am I using the correct approach or is this possible another way?

```
svc := route53.New(session.New())
    input := &route53.ChangeResourceRecordSetsInput{
        ChangeBatch: &route53.ChangeBatch{
            Changes: []*route53.Change{
                {
                    Action: aws.String("UPSERT"),
                    ResourceRecordSet: &route53.ResourceRecordSet{
                        },
                        Name:          aws.String("example.com"),
                        Region:        aws.String("us-east-2"),
                        SetIdentifier: aws.String("Ohio region"),
                        Type:          aws.String("A"),
                    },
                },
            },
            Comment: aws.String("ELB load balancers for example.com"),
        },
        HostedZoneId: aws.String("Z3M3LMPEXAMPLE"),
    }

    result, err := svc.ChangeResourceRecordSets(input)
```

Comment: I'm starting to think I'll need to first read the record set values, create a new record, then delete the old record.  It's not as simple as aws console just clicking the pen icon and typing a new name :(

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I went with to rename a route53 record: 1) Create new record, 2) Delete old record.